# React js Project not successfully install ,How do fix

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[Folder structure Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iey8K.png)

I will create react js project but not successfully install.[Check this img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvC7z.png)

My version:-
npm -v 8.6.0
node v16.14.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's detecting another `package.json` file, could you send your root folder (ReactJS) content, possibly it's detecting another `package.json` file. If it's the case create a different directory where the root has no project created in it. You can use `--force` attribute but that's dangerous and not recommended.

Try this:

```
cd /home/himal/Development 
mkdir new_app 
cd new_app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: how to fix step by step pls

Comment: Please edit the question and the following:
- Folder structure and content (all files and folders in ReactJS)

What you need to do and I suggest is that you create a new folder next to ReactJS and create your app there. try the following:
```
cd /home/himal/Development
mkdir new_app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: not working ,pls check folder structure

Comment: You are trying to install not create a new app, and you are using the wrong command for that. instead of (npx create-react-app my-app) run this => (npm install)